# No args error retrofit request body

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am facing problem while sending json object body using retrofit to the server. Below is the error.

> Failed to invoke public
>   com.nitesh.brill.saleslines._User_Classes.User_PojoClass.UpdatePreviousDetails()
>   with no args

code snippet

// Api endpoint

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("UpdatePreviousDetails/{Id}")
fun updatePreviousDetails(@Path("Id") Id: Int, @Body  updateDetails :UpdatePreviousDetails): Call<UpdatePreviousDetails>
```

//pojo class

```
package com.nitesh.brill.saleslines._User_Classes.User_PojoClass

import java.util.*

/**
 * Created by Nitesh Android on 16-08-2017.
 */
class UpdatePreviousDetails(
        var CompanyName: String? = null!!,
        var Designation: String? = null!!,
        var DateOfJoin: Date? = null!!,
        var DateOfLeaving: Date? = null!!,
        var SectorPreviouslyWorked: String? = null!!,
        var Id: Int? = null!!
) {


}
```

//sending data

```
val details = UpdatePreviousDetails("rr", "asm", date, date, "Pharmaceuticals",3)

val call = apiEndpointInterface!!.updatePreviousDetails(5, details)

call.enqueue(object :Callback<UpdatePreviousDetails> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UpdatePreviousDetails>?, response: Response<UpdatePreviousDetails>?) {
        objUsefullData.showSnackBar("success")

         UsefullData.Log("============="+response!!.body().toString())

    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UpdatePreviousDetails>?, t: Throwable?) {

        objUsefullData.showSnackBar("fail")
        UsefullData.Log("============="+t)

    }

})
```

I am using kotlin language

Answer (score 0):

Your `UpdatePreviousDetails` class has to have a constructor with no params to enable Gson (inside Retrofit) to convert your object into JSON.

**EDIT**

```
class UpdatePreviousDetails() {

    var CompanyName: String? = null
    var Designation: String? = null
    var DateOfJoin: Date? = null
    var DateOfLeaving: Date? = null
    var SectorPreviouslyWorked: String? = null
    var Id: Int? = null

    constructor(
            CompanyName: String?,
            Designation: String?,
            DateOfJoin: Date?,
            DateOfLeaving: Date?,
            SectorPreviouslyWorked: String?,
            Id: Int?
    ) : this() {

        this.CompanyName = CompanyName
        this.Designation = Designation
        this.DateOfJoin = DateOfJoin
        this.DateOfLeaving = DateOfLeaving
        this.SectorPreviouslyWorked = SectorPreviouslyWorked
        this.Id = Id
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can do please give any reffrence

Comment: @NIteshKumar I've just edited my answer, please check it out.

Comment: @NIteshKumar where exactly `NellPointerException` appears? What is `null`?